# compare 2 integer arrays in objective c (mobile applications)

Tags: arrays, cocoa-touch

I am trying to compare 2 arrays, but the problem they are not the same all the time, even if I give 2 same arrays. It will take strange values, and I don't know from where they are coming from. Could anyone help me and give advice to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
for (int i =0; i< array1.count; ++i)
    for(int j=0; j< array2.count; ++j)
    {
        NSLog(@"in the loop");
        NSLog(@"array1 1=%d",[array1 objectAtIndex:i]);

        if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqual: [array2 objectAtIndex:j]])
        {
            NSLog(@"[array1 objectAtIndex:i] = %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSLog(@"[array1 objectAtIndex:j] = %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:j]);

            NSLog(@"am in here winner");
            NSLog(@"the same");
            equals++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try isEqualToNumber:, or even compare `[[array1 objectAtIndex:i] compare: [array2 objectAtIndex:j]] == NSOrderedSame`

Comment: @juman What is printed in the logs? specifically [array1 objectAtIndex:i] ones. Also could you please post the code that creates the arrays, creates the NSNumber instances, and adds them to the arrays?